# custom getter method not working in projection in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, projection

I have one entity named Employee. I have created one interface (projection) also. In my Employee entity, I have one column named gender which stores M/F in the database. But while fetching the result, I am decoding the values M->Male & F->Female. For this, I have overridden the getGender() method and write code there. But this method not working when I use the projection interface.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_NULL)
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_MASTER")
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
    private Integer empId;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "GENDER")
    private String gender;

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender= gender;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender.equals("M")?"Male":"Female";
    }

    .
    .
    .
}

/*Projection*/
public interface EmployeeDetails {
    Integer getEmpId();
    String getName();
    String getGender();
    .
    .
    .
}

/*Repository*/
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer>
    Optional<EmployeeDetails > findByEmpIdIsAndDelDtIsNull(Integer empId);
}

/*Output*/
{
    "empId": "2000001",
    "name": "Mike Thompson",
    "gender": "M",
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: You could make `Gender` an `Enum` in Java. JPA will only store Strings but your mapper turns it into the Java enum, which then can have values associated to the key. Like : `M("Male"),F("Female"),O("Other")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have one more field in Employee i.e. center whose values will be MUM->Mumbai, CHE->Chennai, DEL-Delhi. So can I use the same concept here also?

Comment: Well in that particular case I would consider another entity "Center" that you also store in your base. Then Employee <-> Center would be a oneToMany relationShip.  JPA will handle it for you with the right annotations. Otherwise you would have to manage all Centers hardcoded in an enum.